# how to call and return data from API with AJAX?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, api

Im trying to call an API using ajax.
The api is https://rapidapi.com/brianiswu/api/genius?endpoint=apiendpoint_d2f41ea4-7d5c-4b2d-826a-807bffa7e78f

I cant make it work.I searched in internet but i cant find or understand a solution for my problem. Its easy probably, but please help me
This is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>MusicApp</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
 <form>
  <input type="text" id="inputText">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submitBtn">
 </form>

 <div id="text"></div>
</body>

<script>
 
 $(document).ready(function(){
  var api="1f57380a81msh394cf453f4d1e73p1a0276jsnab0cd43f0df7";

  $('#submit').click(function(){
   artist=$('#inputText').val();

   $.ajax({
    method:"GET",
    url: "https://genius.p.rapidapi.com/search?q=" + artist + "&appid=" + api,
    success:function(resp){
     alert("successfully");
    },
    error:function(){
     alert("Something went TEREBLY WRONG!!!! \nYOU BROKE IT!");
    }
   })
  })
 })
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Inside the success function, find out what `resp` is. Do `console.log(resp);`

Comment: The api you linked has authorization headers required.

Comment: well you need to cancel the form submission or the form is going to submit while you are making the Ajax call.

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to the one below :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var api="1f57380a81msh394cf453f4d1e73p1a0276jsnab0cd43f0df7";

    $('#submitBtn').click(function(){
        artist=$('#inputText').val();

        $.ajax({
            method:"GET",
            url: "https://genius.p.rapidapi.com/search?q=" + artist + "&appid=" + api,
            success:function(resp){
                alert("successfully");
            },
            error:function(){
                alert("Something went TEREBLY WRONG!!!! \nYOU BROKE IT!");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: As I am not authorized to access the API ,I got a 401 in return. But the call is executing.

Comment: Thank you! And how to make the result to show up in the div that i made?

Comment: You can add it in the success callback - $('#text).value = resp

Answer (score 1):

You forgot an essential thing that is preventing you from testing and developing your script: preventing form submit. Do it with `e.preventDefault();`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var api = "1f57380a81msh394cf453f4d1e73p1a0276jsnab0cd43f0df7";

  $('#search-form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var artist = $('#inputText').val();

    $.ajax({
      method: "GET",
      url: "https://genius.p.rapidapi.com/search?q=" + artist + "&appid=" + api,
      success: function(resp) {
        console.log("successfully");
        console.log(resp);
      },
      error: function(resp) {
        console.log("Something went TEREBLY WRONG!!!! \nYOU BROKE IT!");
        console.log(resp);
      }
    })
  })
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>

<form id="search-form" class="form-inline">
  <input type="text" id="inputText" class="form-control">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submitBtn" class="btn btn-default">
</form>

<div id="text"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your token is not valid it gives an unauthorised error.

Once you get the valid one it will work.

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
  var api="1f57380a81msh394cf453f4d1e73p1a0276jsnab0cd43f0df7";

  $('form').submit(function(event){
                        event.preventDefault();
   var artist=$('#inputText').val();

   $.ajax({
    url: "https://genius.p.rapidapi.com/search?q=" + artist + "&appid=" + api,
    success:function(resp){
     alert(resp);
    },
    error:function(e){
     $('#text').text(e.statusText);
    }
   })
  })
 })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>MusicApp</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <form>
  <input type="text" id="inputText">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submitBtn">
 </form>
 <div id="text"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! How to take the valid one? Sorry for the stupid questions.Its very new to me

Comment: Go to https://docs.rapidapi.com/docs/keys to learn how to get your API application key. Not sure is it free or you have to pay for testing. Probably you know that better.